# #DIV/0! error and replace it with zero

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

I am trying the below code to detect DIV/0 error and replace it with Zero or empty cell. but ** line is throwing me error

```
Dim Cell As Range
Dim iSheet as Worksheet
For Each iSheet In sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
    With iSheet
        For Each Cell In .UsedRange
            **If Cell.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then Cell.Value = 0**
        Next Cell
    End With
Next iSheet
```

Comment: See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningErrors.aspx (as per @DisplayName's answer).

Answer (score 2):

seem like you have to check for `cell.Value` being an error before comparing it to an error value

```
If IsError(Cell.Value) Then If Cell.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then Cell.Value = 0
```

so your code becomes

```
Sub mm()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim iSheet As Worksheet
    For Each iSheet In Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
        With iSheet
            For Each Cell In .UsedRange
                If IsError(Cell.Value) Then If Cell.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then Cell.Value = 0
            Next Cell
        End With
    Next iSheet
End Sub
```

another possibility, which limits the cell loop, is the following

```
Sub mm()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim iSheet As Worksheet

    For Each iSheet In Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
        With iSheet
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.UsedRange, "#DIV/0!") Then ' if any Division error found in current sheet used range cells
                For Each Cell In .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors) 'loop through error cells only
                    If Cell.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then Cell.Value = 0
                Next
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @shwetaagnihotri, any feedback?