Write a loop that will check all tabs, a count of sheets, tab color changes based on 3 cell's values
I have a spreadsheet with multiple tabs. This is for pricing. The first tab can be changed in 4 rows to change the profit of each part number which lives on its OWN tab. I would like a code to loop all tabs, counting them and dumping that info on the first Tab sheet(i will need this to count color as well if possible).  Then I would like the macro to check F5, G5, H5.   Depending which one is negative would change the tab color.
F5 is negative G5, H5 positive would turn tab Yellow
G5 and H5 are negative and F5 is positive would turn the tab color Orange.
Also if all 3 cells are all positive numbers i would like the Tab color Green
IF all are negative numbers, then the tab changes to red.
I hope this makes sense, I am currently trying to get a multi-check "if statement" but having issues with: a lot. Thank you to anyone willing to help out.
If Range("G5") <= "-" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A5H3").Tab.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0)
        'do i need an else or End If?'
        If Range("F5") = "-" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A5H3").Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)


Something like:
For Each mySheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    If mySheet.Range("G5") <= 0 Then
        mySheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0)
    ElseIf mySheet.Range("F5") <= 0 Then
        mySheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ElseIf mySheet.Range("E5") <= 0 Then
        mySheet.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    End If

Next mySheet

Should do what I think you want.

Thank you, It appears to work.  The next error is:  When the selection lops to another sheet that has an uncompleted formula showing #DIV/0  it stops the macro.

Thinking another filter could be added to ignore text or anything non-integer.

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793249/div-0-error-and-replace-it-with-zero should show you how to do that

Thank you for the reference to the formula clean up.

My code is running 3 IF statements however, when I use an Else IF i cannot get it to do a Else.     I was wondering if i could write something like this.
If range("F5")  <= 0 and range("G5:H5")  >= 0    then   "one color"
If range("G5")  <= 0 and range("F5", "H5") >= 0     then     "another color"

Public Sub ()
For Each mysheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If mysheet.Range("F5") > "0" Then
mysheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0)
Else: mysheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
If mysheet.Range("G5") > "0" Then
mysheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
Else:
End If
If mysheet.Range("H5") > "0" Then
mysheet.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Else:
End If
Next mysheet
End Sub  This is my Code, left the IF else condition open to get what i needed.

I need help with a code to count the color of tabs on the workbook after this loop above. I would like the data on tab 1 "REF"
